# moving arrowUp/Down to the right

Tags: css

I would like to move the green and red arrow to the left of the numerical value.

[image]

I tried:

```
.arrowDown {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

It doesn't do what I want, the arrows don't move to the right.

```css
.arrowUp,
.arrowDown {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.arrowUp:before,
.arrowDown:before {
    content: "";
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 8.5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.arrowUp:before {
    border-color: transparent transparent #0dff00 transparent;
    top: 37%;
}

.arrowDown:before {
    border-color: #ff0000 transparent transparent transparent;
    top: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
  <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="home-content container ">
    <h1 class="text-center pt-5 pb-3">Indices boursiers</h1>
    <div class="row pt-3 container">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <th scope="col">Indice</th>
                    <th scope="col">Place</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cours</th>
                    <th scope="col">Variation</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date et heure</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="text-center">AED / EUR</th>
                    <td>Euronext Amsterdam</td>
                    <td class="text-end">1 134,65</td>
                    <td class="text-end">
                        <div class="arrowUp"></div>0,31 %</td>
                    <td class="text-center">08/11 - 10:04</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="text-center">ARS / EUR</th>
                    <td>Euronext Amsterdam</td>
                    <td class="text-end">1 134,65 </td>
                    <td class="text-end">
                        <div class="arrowDown"></div>-0.15 %</td>
                    <td class="text-center">08/11 - 10:04</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there is also a `left` property set on `.arrowUp:before, .arrowDown:before` try altering the `left` value and your arrow moves! Or remove the left property and replace it with right.

Like these values for example:

```css
.arrowUp,
.arrowDown {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.arrowUp:before,
.arrowDown:before {
    content: "";
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    /* Changed this */
    right: 50px;
    top: 10px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.arrowUp:before {
    border-color: transparent transparent #0dff00 transparent;
}

.arrowDown:before {
    border-color: #ff0000 transparent transparent transparent;
    /* Added this */
    top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
  <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="home-content container ">
    <h1 class="text-center pt-5 pb-3">Indices boursiers</h1>
    <div class="row pt-3 container">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <th scope="col">Indice</th>
                    <th scope="col">Place</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cours</th>
                    <th scope="col">Variation</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date et heure</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="text-center">AED / EUR</th>
                    <td>Euronext Amsterdam</td>
                    <td class="text-end">1 134,65</td>
                    <td class="text-end">
                        <div class="arrowUp"></div>0,31 %</td>
                    <td class="text-center">08/11 - 10:04</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="text-center">ARS / EUR</th>
                    <td>Euronext Amsterdam</td>
                    <td class="text-end">1 134,65 </td>
                    <td class="text-end">
                        <div class="arrowDown"></div>-0.15 %</td>
                    <td class="text-center">08/11 - 10:04</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```